# How can I save cursor to file .cur?

Tags: c#

I'm working with C# in Visual Studio 2015 on a Winforms application.

In my application I have a function that returns cursor type, and I want to save this cursor into a `.cur` file .

This is my code:

```
public static Cursor CreateCursor(Bitmap bmp, int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot)
{
    IntPtr ptr = bmp.GetHicon();
    IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
    GetIconInfo(ptr, ref tmp);
    tmp.xHotspot = xHotSpot;
    tmp.yHotspot = yHotSpot;
    tmp.fIcon = false;
    ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);
    return new Cursor(ptr);
}

Cursor cr =  CreateCursor(GraphicsMaker(), 20, 20));
```

I want something like this:

```
string MyPath = "c://MyLocation/Cursor.cur";
cr.save(MyPath);
```

So how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as said below:

```
        //YOUR CURSOR
        //Cursor cr =  CreateCursor(GraphicsMaker(), 20, 20)); (For Your question)
        Cursor cr = new Cursor(Cursors.Arrow.Handle);


        //GET ICON FROM YOUR CURSOR HANDLE
        Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(cr.Handle);

        //WRITE TO FILE STREAM
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\users\<<XXXX>>\test.cur", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        ico.Save(fs);


        //TESTING
        Cursor myCursor = new Cursor(@"c:\users\<<XXXX>>\test.cur");
```

I can see many unmanaged resources in your code. Hope you are taking care of disposing them appropriately.

Comment: You mention disposing, but dispose neither the Icon nor the Cursor. Is there a reason to not place those in the using block as well?

Comment: Yes we can.. But as I do not know his exact production code.... I kept it simple for his actual need

Comment: CreateCursor(GraphicsMaker(), 20, 20));
waht is CreateCursor ?

Comment: That I took from OP's code .. it is a user defined function in his code.... I tried in my code with "new Cursor"